# Export Recorder tracks preserve file dates

Tags: linux, android-10, system-apps, miui-12

I need to copy tracks from the system app `Recorder` (apk: `com.android.soundrecorder`) onto Google Drive and/or Linux PC with file dates preserved. I've tried `Send` and `Save` options to phone SD and Google Drive card but the date is lost. (Also it would be very beneficial to convert them from `aac` to `mp3`. The default export makes them `aac`)

Another related question is whether I can find those files in the app data folder directly without exporting ? I've tried to browse `/Android/data/com.android.soundrecorder` but there are no files and warning message that "files are inaccessible due to Android R restrictions ..."

Comment: Please link the app from Play store. It can be confusing to know which app you are talking about or is it a system app of miui